# Доступ к странице пользователей, активировавших свой email

Tags: php, yii2, rules, access-control, behaviors

На сайте реализована регистрация пользователей, активация email по ссылке, отправленной на эту почту. После активации, в БД юзера в поле status записывается значение 1.

Сейчас реализован доступ для незарегестрированных пользователей только к контроллеру login, для зарегестрированных - ко всем контроллерам.

Как сделать, чтобы при попытке доступа к некоторым контроллерам зарегестрированного пользователя, но не активировавшего email (status == 0), происходил редирект на страницу с предложением отправить активационную ссылку на почту ещё раз?

Попробовал следующий код:

```
public function behaviors()
{

    return [
        'access' => [
            'class' => AccessControl::className(),

            'rules' => [
                [
                    'allow' => true,
                    'controllers' => ['login'],
                    'roles' => ['?'],   
                ],
                [
                    'allow' => true,
                    'controllers' => ['tabs', 'login', 'settings', 'fin-item', 'fin-event', 'cat-item-edit', 'edit-fin-event', 'balance'],                      
                    'roles' => ['@'],

                ],
                [
                    'allow' => false,
                    'controllers' => ['tabs', 'login', 'settings', 'fin-item', 'fin-event', 'cat-item-edit', 'edit-fin-event', 'balance'],
                    'matchCallback' => function ( $rule, $action ) {

                        return Yii::$app->user->identity->status == User::STATUS_NOT_ACTIVE;
                    },
                    'denyCallback' => function ( $rule, $action ) {

                        return $action->controller->redirect('login/send-activation-mail');
                    },
                    'roles' => ['@'],
                ],                  
            ],
        ],
    ];
}
```

Однако никакого редиректа не происходит, незарегистрированный пользователь попадает только на login контроллер, а зарегистрированный на все контроллеры, независимо от состояния поля status.

Answer (score 0):

Кроме статуса, у пользователя должно быть свойство "роль". Например: admin, user, blocked, banned, wait итд, итп.

По этому свойству можно дать доступ к определенным экшенам в контроллере. 
А у вас проверка идет по свойству гость или не гость, не зависимо от статуса.